# Split tuple / collection into instances of pattern

Tags: python

I have a tuple [but it can be any collection] that contains elements:

```
tple = (1.02, 'a', 'b', 1.02, 'a', 'b')
```

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of times the pattern `(1.02, 'a', 'b')` occurs within the tuple.  The pattern may not exist at all, in which case I would want to return `0`.

Is there such a way?

Comment: How about overlapping patterns, can they occured?

Comment: Yes, in theory they could I suppose. Good question.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is *pattern*?  just some formal definition?

Comment: Just some collection of items I'm trying to match on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools):

```
from itertools import tee


def wise(iterable):
    """Iterate over contiguous overlapping chunks"""
    a, b, c = tee(iterable, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return zip(a, b, c)


tple = (1.02, 'a', 'b', 1.02, 'a', 'b')
pattern = (1.02, 'a', 'b')

res = sum(i == pattern for i in wise(tple))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

The function wise, is a generalization of [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise). For the above example it returns something similar to:

```
[(1.02, 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 1.02), ('b', 1.02, 'a'), (1.02, 'a', 'b')]
```

Note that by using itertools `tple` can be any collection. The expression:

```
res = sum(i == pattern for i in wise(tple))
```

is equivalent to the following for-loop:

```
res = 0
for i in wise(tple):
    if pattern == i:
        res += 1
print(res)
```

If you want to iterate in chunks of different lengths, use the following general `wise` function:

```
def wise(iterable, n=3):
    """Iterate over contiguous overlapping chunks"""
    its = tee(iterable, n)
    for i, it in enumerate(its):
        for _ in range(i):
            next(it)
    return zip(*its)
```

**UPDATE**

The general function can be linear as suggested by @KellyBundy:

```
def wise(iterable, n=3):
    """Iterate over contiguous overlapping chunks"""
    its = []
    for _ in range(n):
        iterable, it = tee(iterable)
        its.append(it)
        next(iterable, None)
    return zip(*its)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Does the 3 in tee(iterable, 3) have much relevance to the pattern that I pass in?  Sometimes the pattern is 4 values long, other times 3 values long etc

Comment: @keynesiancross Yes, it does. Included a general function that should work for any pattern length

Comment: For the general one at the end, better use `enumerate` and `next(it, None)`. Could also [initialize in O(n)](https://tio.run/##TU/LbsJADLzvV1i5ZIMipBKKqkp8QC/9gaqqAjjBbWKvvE4f/HxYwqPMzeMZzzj82V64ego6jo1KD2SoJtJFoD6IGhiiczts4Ici@tO63nRYAq@r4tlBQpZlLyfaEOQbFbbCRu0gQ5zmrg6BuIXtfuCvmMSTiSzCGt7ep6ERhQ8gBq25Rc@Xw2fdNZAsGVKbW4fiThTnKQV5l5b/NOOv3TV@Fb54FG1QhgMFP0vewrmgxOY7iub7Ovg8n38KcXl@On9YVMvHVV7CskgYxyM) instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this if you're trying out for the One-Line Olympics:

```
>>> tple = (1.02, 'a', 'b', 1.02, 'a', 'b')
>>> pattern = (1.02, 'a', 'b')
>>> sum(tple[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern for i in range(len(tple)-len(pattern)+1))
2
```

It should also work for patterns of any length:

```
>>> pattern = (1.02,)
>>> sum(tple[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern for i in range(len(tple)-len(pattern)+1))
2
```

It will return `0` if the pattern is longer than the tuple, or if the pattern is not found:

```
>>> pattern = (1.02, 'a', 'b', 1.02, 'a', 'b', 'c')
>>> sum(tple[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern for i in range(len(tple)-len(pattern)+1))
0
>>> pattern = (1.03,)
>>> sum(tple[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern for i in range(len(tple)-len(pattern)+1))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a simple and straightforward way to do so:

```
# collection = ...
count = 0
for ind in range(2, len(collection)):
    if collection [ind-2] == 1.02 and collection [ind-1] == 'a' and collection [ind] == 'b':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Want to point this out, that this code is valid with any type that is subscritable and can be passed to len(). But notice, that length of collection should be >= 3 (If otherwise it's trivial).